# Symfony form handleRequest not populating

Tags: php, forms, symfony-3.1

I have a symfony 3 form. And I'm trying to populate it with handleRequest like this:

```
$user = new User();
$userForm = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
print_r($request->request->all());
$userForm->handleRequest($request);

print_r($userForm->getData());
```

The output I get is:

```
Array
(
    [firstName] => test
    [last_name] => test
    [email] => test@test.test
    [password] => erkeferke
    [gender] => F
    [supervisor] => 1
)
AppBundle\Entity\User Object
(
    [id:AppBundle\Entity\User:private] => 
    [firstName] => 
    [lastName:AppBundle\Entity\User:private] => 
    [email:AppBundle\Entity\User:private] => 
    [password:AppBundle\Entity\User:private] => 
    [photo:AppBundle\Entity\User:private] => 
    [gender:AppBundle\Entity\User:private] => 
    [supervisor:AppBundle\Entity\User:private] => 
    [duties:AppBundle\Entity\User:private] => 
    [lastLogin:AppBundle\Entity\User:private] => 
    [createdAt:AppBundle\Entity\User:private] => 
    [updatedAt:AppBundle\Entity\User:private] => 
    [deletedAt:AppBundle\Entity\User:private] => 
)
```

Any idea why it's not populating?

Comment: When are you doing `$userForm->getData()` it should be done after request has been handled and after checking `$userForm->isValid()`.

Comment: Ok, it reports that it's not valid. But I have no idea how to get the errors.

Comment: see my example code below and try to match your code structure like the one I have shown. Once you get the idea, you can tweak however you like it. Let us know if you have any confusions.

Comment: JSON: as this comes up when searching for JSON data input - for JSON, you have to manually decode the data `json_decode($request->getContent(), true)` and manually submit them if decoded properly `$form->submit($data);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To automatically populate entity from form request, you have to bind your entity to the FormType class. You might be missing this bind from your `UserType` class. In form `UserType` you should add a method `configureOptions` inside it you specify the `entity class name` in `data_class` key. To have more insights into it see [Symfony Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html) and scroll down to `Setting the data_class` topic. Also See example below where I have listed the usage.

```
<?php namespace AppBundle\Form;

...

class SiteType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
       // define form fields
    }


    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Site', // Entity to resolve to
        ));
    }
}
```

Now, when you use the form, your entity is resolved from the request as shown below `$site = $form->getData()` will return `Site` entity. This is quite tricky to get right at the first time. You have to practice it a lot until you get hang of it. Let us know if you have confusions following it.

```
 /**
 *
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 *
 * @Route("/sites/create", name="_create_site")
 */
public function createSite(Request $request)
{
    $site = new Site;
    $form = $this->createForm(SiteType::class, $site);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {           
        $site = $form->getData();  // It will return Site Entity

        ...

        $this->addFlash('success', 'Record added successfully.');
    }

    return $this->render('sites/create.html.twig', [
        'site_form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: thanks. it works. Btw, any idea why form get data returns multiple entries of type User? I'm dumbfounded

Comment: If it works for you then please mark my answer as accepted answer. I didn't get what do you  mean by multiple entries of type User ?

Comment: Hey @Samundra ! Could you help me with this problem too, please? I've stuck for weeks, but my form is a bit more complicated built that this one. How is it better to discuss with avoiding possible duplication of the question on the website? Thanks

Comment: Hi @PaulBurilichev I would suggest to pen a new thread and link this question. That way you would have reference as well.

Comment: @Samundra that's my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56639112/symfony-4-why-submitted-does-form-just-partially-populate-the-model