# Symfony 4. Why does submitted Form just partially populate the Model?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

A bit in the panic - I am generating Symfony form for a complex search, i.e. mapped data to the entity will be used just for a search query building.

I create simple form, model, some extended types from ChoiceType for prepopulation choices by some logic. The form is submitted with GET method.

In the model you find `maker` and `model` fields for example. The latter populated on the frontend with AJAX, after maker has been selected. When I do submit the form, and `maker` and `model` have non-default value, the `handleRequest` only populates the `maker` property of the Model, but the `model` is left empty. Also the checkboxes are correctly populated if checked. All in all, `$form->getData()` returns just Maker and checkboxes, other fields are null. `$request->query` has all parameters.

The data mappers are senseless here. And also there is nothing to transform in the data, the Model is mostly from scalar values. The request contains everything, but it is not handled correctly. I tried to implement `ChoiceLoaderInterface`, but that doesn't work for me, because during loading choices I have to have access to the `options` of the form, which I don't (I used this article https://speakerdeck.com/heahdude/symfony-forms-use-cases-and-optimization).

I am using Symfony 4.2.4; PHP 7.2.

**Controller's method**

```php
/**
     * @Route("/search/car", name="car_search", methods={"GET"})
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function carSearchAction(Request $request)
    {
        $carModel = new CarSimpleSearchModel();
        $form     = $this->createForm(CarSimpleSearchType::class, $carModel);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $form->getData();

        .....
    }
```

**CarSimpleSearchModel**

```php
class CarSimpleSearchModel
{
    public $maker;
    public $model;
    public $priceFrom;
    public $priceTo;
    public $yearFrom;
    public $yearTo;
    public $isCompanyOwner;
    public $isPrivateOwners;
    public $isRoublePrice;
}
```

**CarSimpleSearchType the form**

```php
class CarSimpleSearchType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $urlGenerator;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('vehicle_type', HiddenType::class, [
                'data' => VehicleTypeType::CAR,
                'mapped' => false,
            ])
            ->add('maker', CarMakerSelectType::class)
            ->add('model', CarModelsSelectType::class)
            ->add(
                'priceFrom',
                VehiclePriceRangeType::class,
                [
                    'vehicle_type' => VehicleTypeType::CAR,
                ]
            )
            ->add(
                'priceTo',
                VehiclePriceRangeType::class,
                [
                    'vehicle_type' => VehicleTypeType::CAR,
                ]
            )
            ->add(
                'yearFrom',
                VehicleYearRangeType::class,
                [
                    'vehicle_type' => VehicleTypeType::CAR,
                ]
            )
            ->add(
                'yearTo',
                VehicleYearRangeType::class,
                [
                    'vehicle_type' => VehicleTypeType::CAR,
                ]
            )
            ->add('isCompanyOwner', CheckboxType::class)
            ->add('isPrivateOwners', CheckboxType::class)
            ->add('isRoublePrice', CheckboxType::class)
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'data_class' => CarSimpleSearchModel::class,
                'compound'   => true,
                'method'     => 'GET',
                'required'   => false,
                'action'     => $this->urlGenerator->generate('car_search'),
            ]
        );
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'car_search_form';
    }
}
```

**CarMakerSelectType field**

```php
class CarMakerSelectType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @var VehicleExtractorService
     */
    private $extractor;

    /**
     * VehicleMakerSelectType constructor.
     *
     * @param VehicleExtractorService $extractor
     */
    public function __construct(VehicleExtractorService $extractor)
    {
        $this->extractor = $extractor;
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return ChoiceType::class;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'placeholder'  => null,
                'vehicle_type' => null,
                'choices'      => $this->getVariants(),
            ]
        );
    }

    private function getVariants()
    {
        $makers  = $this->extractor->getMakersByVehicleType(VehicleTypeType::CAR);
        $choices = [];

        foreach ($makers as $maker) {
            $choices[$maker['name']] = $maker['id'];
        }

        return $choices;
    }
}
```

**CarModelSelectType field**

```php
class CarModelsSelectType extends AbstractType
{
    private $extractor;
    public function __construct(VehicleExtractorService $extractor)
    {
        $this->extractor = $extractor;
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return ChoiceType::class;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'disabled'    => true,
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

**VehiclePriceRangeType field**

```php
class VehiclePriceRangeType extends AbstractType
{
    private $extractor;

    public function __construct(VehicleExtractorService $extractor)
    {
        $this->extractor = $extractor;
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return ChoiceType::class;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'vehicle_type' => null,
            ]
        );
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        foreach ($this->getRange($options['vehicle_type']) as $value) {
            $view->vars['choices'][] = new ChoiceView($value, $value, $value);
        }
    }

    private function getRange(int $vehicleType)
    {
        return PriceRangeGenerator::generate($this->extractor->getMaxVehiclePrice($vehicleType));
    }
}
```

**VehicleYearRangeType field**

```php
class VehicleYearRangeType extends AbstractType
{
    private $extractor;

    public function __construct(VehicleExtractorService $extractorService)
    {
        $this->extractor = $extractorService;
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return ChoiceType::class;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'vehicle_type' => null,
            ]
        );
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        foreach ($this->getRange($options['vehicle_type']) as $value) {
            $view->vars['choices'][] = new ChoiceView($value, $value, $value);
        }
    }

    protected function getRange(int $vehicleType): array
    {
        $yearRange = RangeGenerator::generate(
            $this->extractor->getMinYear($vehicleType),
            $this->extractor->getMaxYear($vehicleType),
            1,
            true,
            true
        );

        return $yearRange;
    }
}
```

So, I can use the raw data from the `Request` and manually validate-populate the model and send to further processing, but I guess that's not the Right Way, and I want to populated the form by the framework. How can I ?..

Comment: I'm guessing this is a [`PRE_SUBMIT` Event](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html#a-the-formevents-pre-submit-event) issue, since you created the form with a disabled `CarModelSelectType` with no `choice`s, so the value submitted is considered invalid. But if that was the case, you should see an exception, I think. If that's the problem you'll have to modify the form to add the valid choices for `Model` based on the `Maker` selection.

Comment: Hey @msg , I thought this way, and I tried to populate the `Model` field, but no success. I feel, that I close to the solution. Now I am looking at the probably incorrect transformation, because my choices are generated dynamically, and Symfony's `class ChoiceToValueTransformer` aren't able to resolve dynamically generated choices.

Comment: The reason is that choices are populated not by `choices` or `choices_loader`. I can't do that, because I need to populate choices later by Ajax, or really after the rest configuration of the field are set.
@msg could you point me the direction you are talking about, please?
And yes, I debugged the handling of the request and it throws exceptions, but those are implicit and don't thrown to the browser or `/var/log/dev.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I had a dependent `EntityType` populated by ajax that is initially disabled. Since `choices` where `null`, it was returning an `InvalidValueException` on submission. What I had to do is create an `EventListener` and add the valid `choices` for the current 'main' field. This is basically it, more or less adapted to your case.

Original form:

```
// Setup Fields
$builder
    ->add('maker', CarMakerSelectType::class)
    ->add('model', CarModelsSelectType::class, [
            'choices' => [],
            // I was setting the disabled on a Event::PRE_SET_DATA if previous field was null
            // since I could be loading values from the database but I guess you can do it here
            'attr' => ['disabled' => 'disabled'],
        ]
    );
$builder->addEventSubscriber(new ModelListener($this->extractor));
```

Event Subscriber that adds back valid choices:

```
class ModelListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function __construct(VehicleExtractorService $extractor)
    {
        $this->extractor = $extractor;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT => 'onPreSubmitData',
        ];
    }

    public function onPreSubmitData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        // At this point you get only the scalar values, Model hasn't been transformed yet
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        $maker_id = $data['maker'];
            $model= $form->get('model');
            $options = $model->getConfig()->getOptions();

            if (!empty($maker_id)) {
                unset($options['attr']['disabled']);
                $options['choices'] = $this->extractor->getModelsFor($maker_id);

                $form->remove('model');
                $form->add('model', CarModelsSelectType::class, $options );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @msg I've got the idea. And tried - unsuccessful. Just the note, that we should pass explicit the $extractor to the subscriber, since it is created with `new`. Yes, it went to the Subscriber and the form has been updated, but the CarSimpleSearchModel is not populated with the `model` id.

And the reason of not working choices for price and year seems like I need to populate fields based on `$options` passed to fields during the form building, but not after that, like `buildView()` or `finishView()`

Comment: You are right about the extractor, I've updated the answer for reference. Can you get the data there in the event? You might be right in that adding the `ChoiceView` manually is overwriting the variables. But you still may be able to do it on `PRE_SET_DATA`? Not 100%.

Comment: Yea, thanks for the update. But what do you think that PRE_SUBMIT didn't change the result of the model field population?

BTW, I will true to PRE_SET_DATA for price and year.

Comment: UPD. With `PRE_SUBMIT` I have healed the `priceFrom` and `priceTo` fields. The model has been populated after submit. Despite of sameness of the fields to `yearFrom` and `yearTo` the latter aren't managed by this event.

Comment: Finally, I hit that! 
There were some logical mistypes and misuses. I mean I significantly simplified the form and how it inits, plus your suggestion, and viola. Thanks, man.